# Handle Invalid URL in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing, invalid-url

How to handle invalid URLs in MVC?

For ex.: When the user enters http://localhost/User/MyProfile instead of
http://localhost/User/Profile, it will throw an exception.

How to handle this request?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need first to add a custom Error page url in the web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/404" />
```

And add a controller to handle the invalid urls:

```
public class ErrorController:Controller
    {
        [ActionName("404")]
        public ActionResult Error404()
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

And if you want to redirect the user to the home page then you  don't need the Error controller just modify the custom error tag:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Index" />
```

Comment: Actually, i will need this soon. I helped myself too (favorited this question).

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
// Show a 404 error page for anything else.
    routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}",
    new { controller = "Error", action = "404" }
);
```

Comment: ya exactly like that, but when i used that code, its not redirecting to the specified page. Still showing "The resource cannot be found.". I have added the following in Global.asax.cs:

routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

Answer (score 0):

I think every request should be redirected to the front controller, so wrap your code inside a try/catch block that will intercept the exception, and maybe you can redirect to the homepage in the catch block or simply raise a 404 error with an exception handler.

What is your server language ?

Comment: It's tagged asp.net-mvc-routing

Comment: Sorry for being irrelevant ^^