# C# MVC: Bind Http Errors to specific error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to direct specific errors to specific error pages or views (e.g. Error404.aspx) through MVC?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903537/handle-invalid-url-in-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

I've used the `<customErrors>` section of the web.config file to handle this in the past. This works in MVC and/or webforms.

If you don't like that approach, check out [this](http://www.genericerror.com/blog/2009/01/27/ASPNetMVCCustomErrorPages.aspx) article for a custom solution, and [this](http://robertschultz.wordpress.com/2009/05/11/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-pages/) one for some workarounds on the default architecture.