# not redirected to login page after Routeconfig.cs set to go default page on url call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing

I set routeConfig.cs as below

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "404-PageNotFound",
        url: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "PageNotFound" }
        );
```

but still when I hit website url it navigate me to 404-page not found as I am not using any contoller name and action name in my url.Like www.this.com
not www.this.com/Home.Index.It should reddirect me to Login page when I put url as www.this.com
Any help please.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but I highly recommend using routing attributes rather than the routeConfig file.  They have many benefits, including being much easier to maintain.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 0):

I have took answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903537/handle-invalid-url-in-mvc):

You have to in web.config in section `<system.web>` add:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Index" />
```

Did you mean this?

Comment: we are redirecting to another page when error occurs so if custom Error occurs it will redirect to   ~/Home/Index. we don't need this what we need is that when we put web url in url address bar it must default redirect to Home login page not error page.

Comment: Maybe you try to prevent call action by unautorized user?